Prove that the Jacobi method converges for every $2 \times 2$ symetric definite positive matrix
Prove that the Jacobi method converges for every $2 \times 2$ system given by a symetrical definite positive matrix.
I tried building the iteration matrix $B_J = -D^{-1} (L+U)$ given a matrix
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ 
b & d 
\end{pmatrix}$$
then
$$
B_J=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac{b}{a} \\ 
\frac{b}{d} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I already calculated the spectral radius and got that
$$
|\lambda| = \left|\frac{b}{\sqrt{ad}}\right|
$$
but got stuck trying to prove that $\rho(B_J) = |\lambda| < 1$ .
Thanks in advance.

Can you show how you calculated the spectral radius perhaps? Have you used the assumption that $A$ is positive definite anywhere?

I had not used it at all, and solved it with your suggestion: as $A$ is positive definite, then by Sylvester criterion, $a>0$ and, in particular, $\det (A) = ad-b^2 > 0$. Therefore, $\frac{b}{(ad)^{\frac{1}{2}}} < 1$ . Thank you.

you're welcome!
